# How do you access mediaquery.of(context).width.height outside of a build method?

Tags: flutter

I don't specifically need to access the mediaquery method, just anything that will return a the native devices height and width. What I'm trying to achieve is a reactive theme that will scale  text sizes based on a device's size.

Comment: What are you actually trying to access? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: device dimensions

Comment: But where would you need that, that couldn’t have access to a context? I suppose you need the dimensions to render something and if you are going to render, you’re probably covered by a `BuildContext`.

Comment: I'm defining a theme and I want to scale text based on a users device dimensions. where I define my theme I don't have access to a buildcontext.

Comment: Do you know that a`Text` actually already scales automatically accordingly to pixel density right? If you’re going for a theme that has some `fontSize` conditions (ie, if big screen fontsize: 40 if not, to 20) then I suggest you to take advantage of the `TextTheme` property of the `ThemeData` and then use it within your `build` picking, for example, `Theme.of(context).textTheme.display3` if screen is big of `display1` if small. But this is just an example, that I’m trying to say is that your theme ideally should use statically properties.

Comment: Anyway, take a look at [flutter_screenutil](https://github.com/OpenFlutter/flutter_screenutil) package. May be of your interest.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what I do in my apps, I don't want to use mediacontext too(as sometimes I don't have the context), take a look at the following example:

https://github.com/lhcdims/statemanagement02

Try to look at the class 'sv' inside lib/ScreenVariables.dart

And call sv.init() inside main.dart, then you can use sv.screenwidth, sv.defaultfontsize ...etc anywhere in any dart files.

Comment: What's the overhead of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

It is simple to do that. This is how I do it in a StatefulWidget:

```
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
 
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
 
   var screenHeight = window.physicalSize.height / window.devicePixelRatio;
   var screenWidth = window.physicalSize.width / window.devicePixelRatio;
   .    .    .    .
   .    .    .    .
   .    .    .    .
```

Comment: no getter for physicalSize in recent Flutter and Dart.

Comment: see here, need to `import 'dart:ui'`

Answer (score -1):

You can't access the Context object outside the build method directly. You can either pass the Context object through from inside the build method to the separate build function.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Container(
    children: buildChildren(context)
  );
}

Widget buildChildren(BuildContext context){
  ...
}
```