# Adjust textSize, widget sizes based on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing for an app for mobile devices and android tv(48 inches TV). I adjust fontSize, widget sizes using `MediaQuery`. Is there any better way to do these things?

```
static double width(BuildContext context) => MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

height: height * 1 / 32,

textSize: height * 1 / 32
```

Line > Container widget

```
CustomLine(
              width: width * (1 / 8),
              height: height * (1 / 512),
              color: Palette.white,
            ),
```

Comment: check [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you want the size with or without the safe Area :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57237870/12937274

You can also try that:

```
 import 'dart:ui';

window.physicalSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never developed anything for such a screen, but I have used the [auto_size_text package](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) in the past to easily size text automatically based on available space, and it works really well. With this package, you don't need to handle the sizings explicitly for every `Text`.

Another way of doing it could be to use the [LayoutBuilder class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to get the available space around your `Text` widget, and handle the proper sizing yourself.