# Flutter relative position of elements inside container

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following slightly modified standart app, in which
the button and the result are put in a container.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: containerWidget()
      ),
    );
  }
}

class containerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _containerWidgetState createState() => _containerWidgetState();
}

class _containerWidgetState extends State<containerWidget> {

  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      height : 300,
      width  : 300,
      child:
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'You have pushed the button this many times:',
          ),
          Text(
            '$_counter',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                  tooltip: 'Increment',
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                
              ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In a first step, I would like to get the width and size of the screen to set the relative position of the container widget within the screen.

In a second step, I would like to modify the position of the Button within the Container widget, that means either

- by getting the absolute position of the container to set the absolute position of the button w.r.t the screen size

or

- by setting the relative position of the button inside the container

```
Positioned(left: 30.0,
           top: 50.0,
           child: Container(
                width: 100.0,
                height: 80.0,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                child: ...
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It sounds like you should be able to accomplish this using center widgets and padding, or at least with Flex widgets.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to have complete controll over positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the height and width of the screen you can check ou this answer :
[Flutter screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553402/flutter-screen-size)

if you'd like to move the button relative to the parent Container, you can wrap the container with a Stack widget, and set the container and button as its children(meaning you have to move the button outside the container), then simply wrap the button with a Positioned widget and use arguments `right : , left : , top : , bottom : ,` to control the button's position with respect to the container

```
//for example, this means the container is 30px to the left and 50px from the top
Positioned(left: 30.0,
           top: 50.0,
           child: Container()),
```