# Flutter Media Query MediaQuery.of(context).size.height doesn't give the accurate Height or Width. As got from google

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Viewport getting from flutter using MediaQuery.of(context).size.height. 411.4285X866.285

[image: Device Actual Viewport 412x914]

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Is this answer a clue for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57237870/10659482

Comment: follow the link in the previous comment you will find a detailed explanation. but in short, your code will return the height and width with padding so that your app doesn't interfere with the device navigation bar and the structural constrains hiding some portions of your app. A better explanation would be it return the `context` width and height where the widgets can be painted.

Comment: I am honored to see your comment. Actually, none of the solutions is working. It varies from device to device for android. For iOS it's fine. I mean  "MediaQuery.of(context).size" is not working properly for android devices. If you have time you can do a check.