# Is there any differences between `MediaQuery.of(context).size` and `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize`?

Tags: flutter, dart

The following two:

1. `MediaQuery.of(context).size`
2. `WidgetsBinding.instance.window.physicalSize / binding.window.devicePixelRatio`

Do they have differences, or are they *always* equivalent?

I have checked the doc without useful information.

Comment: they are the same, check the sources of `WidgetsApp` for more info

Answer (score 1):

[How to Determine Screen Height and Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49553402/how-to-determine-screen-height-and-width)

According to ertgrull's answer on this post, it seems that the first option to your question returns logical pixels, while the second returns physical pixels.

You could read up more on the link that he posted together with his answer.

Comment: I have divided devicePixelRatio so it is logical :)