# Lock Device Orientation Conditionally in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to Lock Device Orientation based on the screen size, if the screen size is less than 430x932 I'd like to lock the orientation to portrait, and if the size is greater than it I'd like to lock the orientation do landscape.

I already did a simples lock, could someone help me to create this conditional?

This is what I already did.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


Future lockPortrait() async {

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
}
```

Comment: To get screen size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57237870/13625293

Answer (score 3):

You can get the size of you screen device with:

```
Size size = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context);
double width = size.width;
double height = size.height;
```

And then do your comparison, like:

```
if(width < 430 && height < 932) {
// set portrait here 
} else {
// set landscape here
}
```